# Gráfico de área empilhado

Tags: r, gráfico, chart

Estou tentando fazer um gráfico de área conforme o da imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas estou usando uma base de dados diferente da utilizada para esse gráfico e estou tendo algumas dúvidas:

**1- Estou usando o código a seguir:**

```
ggplot(novo, aes(x = Commissioned, y = somaacumulada)) +
  theme_bw()+
  geom_area(position = position_dodge(width = 0),alpha=0.8, aes(fill=Country)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks= "10 years", labels = date_format("%Y"))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,37000,1000)) +
  xlab('Ano') +ylab('Potência Instalada [MW]')
```

O resultado que estou obtendo com esse código é o seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Da para perceber que não está acontecendo o empilhamento das áreas, porém não sei como fazer isso no código. Uma coisa que eu pensei seria o fato de que as `country` não tem dados para todos os anos, por exemplo, a Austria tem a `somaacumulada` para 2017, mas não tem para 2000.

**2-** Também gostaria de limitar o eixo X para mostrar os valores somente entre os anos 1900 e 2020, tentei inserir o código

```
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(as.Date('01-01-1900'), as.Date('01-01-2020')))
```

Porem é exibido um gráfico vazio.

**3-** Como faço para mudar a cor das áreas do gráfico? Por exemplo, se eu quiser escolher a cor de cada país separadamente.

**4- Base de dados**

````
"Rated Power","Country","Commissioned","d","m","a","somaacumulada"
1.14,"Resto do mundo",1985-01-01,1,1,1985,17451.5
1.28,"Japan",1995-01-01,1,1,1995,16969.78
1.7,"Resto do mundo",1966-01-01,1,1,1966,2542.3
2,"China",1992-11-01,1,11,1992,485
3.5,"Germany",1973-01-01,1,1,1973,1346.7
3.6,"Spain",1955-01-01,1,1,1955,10.8
4.6,"Resto do mundo",1957-01-01,1,1,1957,238.6
7,"Austria",1969-01-01,1,1,1969,352
7.2,"Spain",1929-01-01,1,1,1929,7.2
8.5,"United States",1954-01-01,1,1,1954,37.5
11,"France",1951-01-01,1,1,1951,11
11.3,"Spain",2014-06-27,27,6,2014,6983.7
12,"India",1976-01-01,1,1,1976,162
13.5,"Japan",1961-01-01,1,1,1961,13.5
14,"Spain",1966-01-01,1,1,1966,564.8
15.9,"Resto do mundo",1969-01-01,1,1,1969,2758.2
17,"Resto do mundo",1986-01-01,1,1,1986,18791.5
22,"China",1973-11-01,1,11,1973,63
24,"Resto do mundo",1953-01-01,1,1,1953,234
25.2,"United States",1973-01-01,1,1,1973,6518.7
28,"United States",1972-01-01,1,1,1972,5277.5
29,"United States",1929-01-01,1,1,1929,29
30,"Resto do mundo",1937-01-01,1,1,1937,165
30.8,"Resto do mundo",1989-01-01,1,1,1989,20912.3
35,"Germany",1959-01-01,1,1,1959,404
36.5,"Italy",1965-01-01,1,1,1965,489.7
37,"Resto do mundo",2016-12-31,31,12,2016,33017.7
40,"Resto do mundo",1974-01-01,1,1,1974,5482.2
40,"United States",2012-09-14,14,9,2012,22560.7
41,"China",1968-05-01,1,5,1968,41
42,"Italy",1968-01-01,1,1,1968,646.7
45,"Resto do mundo",1944-01-01,1,1,1944,210
45,"United States",1994-01-01,1,1,1994,21425.7
48,"France",1957-01-01,1,1,1957,59
49,"Germany",1983-01-01,1,1,1983,3999.7
49.2,"Germany",1960-01-01,1,1,1960,453.2
50,"Austria",2011-01-01,1,1,2011,3200
50,"United States",1971-08-01,1,8,1971,5249.5
53,"Resto do mundo",1990-01-01,1,1,1990,20965.3
54,"Spain",1982-01-01,1,1,1982,2786.3
58,"United States",1984-01-01,1,1,1984,15300.9
60,"Resto do mundo",1972-01-01,1,1,1972,3817.2
68,"Resto do mundo",1964-01-01,1,1,1964,1004.6
70,"China",2000-12-01,1,12,2000,1605
80,"China",2000-01-01,1,1,2000,1535
80,"China",1997-12-01,1,12,1997,655
80,"Germany",1968-01-01,1,1,1968,1203.2
80,"Italy",1960-01-01,1,1,1960,316
80,"Italy",1905-04-11,11,4,1905,80
80,"Resto do mundo",1977-01-01,1,1,1977,7542.2
82.8,"Resto do mundo",1997-01-01,1,1,1997,25361.1
88.5,"Spain",1969-01-01,1,1,1969,785.3
90,"China",1997-05-01,1,5,1997,575
90,"Germany",1964-01-01,1,1,1964,763.2
90,"Spain",1971-01-01,1,1,1971,1685.3
97,"United States",1972-12-31,31,12,1972,6493.5
99,"Germany",1955-01-01,1,1,1955,249
102,"China",2002-06-01,1,6,2002,5943
108,"Austria",1981-01-01,1,1,1981,2125
111,"Spain",1982-01-01,1,1,1982,2732.3
113,"Austria",1956-01-01,1,1,1956,113
115,"Italy",1966-01-01,1,1,1966,604.7
120,"Austria",1979-01-01,1,1,1979,1728
120,"China",2005-09-01,1,9,2005,6063
120,"Germany",1958-10-15,15,10,1958,369
125,"Resto do mundo",1972-01-01,1,1,1972,3942.2
132,"Spain",1966-01-01,1,1,1966,696.8
133,"Spain",1978-01-01,1,1,1978,2621.3
134,"Italy",1980-01-01,1,1,1980,3128.7
135,"Resto do mundo",1937-01-01,1,1,1937,135
137,"Japan",1961-01-01,1,1,1961,150.5
137.2,"Italy",1964-01-01,1,1,1964,453.2
140,"Austria",2011-06-01,1,6,2011,3150
140,"Germany",1969-01-01,1,1,1969,1343.2
140,"Germany",2010-04-20,20,4,2010,5352.7
140,"Resto do mundo",1988-01-01,1,1,1988,20481.5
143,"Resto do mundo",1981-01-19,19,1,1981,10669.2
145,"Resto do mundo",2016-12-31,31,12,2016,32980.7
150,"Germany",1951-01-01,1,1,1951,150
150,"India",1951-01-01,1,1,1951,150
153,"Germany",1989-08-08,8,8,1989,4152.7
156,"Italy",1949-01-01,1,1,1949,236
156,"Resto do mundo",1971-01-01,1,1,1971,3154.2
158,"Italy",2005-11-01,1,11,2005,7070.7
160,"Resto do mundo",1977-01-01,1,1,1977,7462.2
160,"Resto do mundo",1988-01-01,1,1,1988,20341.5
164,"Germany",1976-01-01,1,1,1976,1990.7
164,"Resto do mundo",1958-01-01,1,1,1958,402.6
171,"Resto do mundo",1996-01-01,1,1,1996,24244.3
174,"Resto do mundo",1958-01-01,1,1,1958,576.6
180,"Resto do mundo",1979-08-08,8,8,1979,10526.2
185,"Resto do mundo",2010-04-01,1,4,2010,29566.7
185,"United States",1956-05-24,24,5,1956,222.5
191.6,"Resto do mundo",2005-01-01,1,1,2005,29381.7
198,"Resto do mundo",1975-01-01,1,1,1975,6272.2
199.8,"United States",1987-01-01,1,1,1987,20315.7
200,"Japan",2014-10-01,1,10,2014,24541.78
200,"Japan",1974-11-01,1,11,1974,4712.5
200,"Japan",2015-11-01,1,11,2015,25141.78
200,"Resto do mundo",1968-01-01,1,1,1968,2742.3
200,"United States",1981-01-01,1,1,1981,15242.9
208,"United States",1979-12-01,1,12,1979,15042.9
210,"Italy",1971-01-01,1,1,1971,856.7
211,"Resto do mundo",2015-01-01,1,1,2015,31817.7
215,"Spain",1973-01-01,1,1,1973,1900.3
219.1,"Spain",1985-01-01,1,1,1985,3365.4
220,"Germany",1964-01-01,1,1,1964,673.2
220,"Japan",1968-01-01,1,1,1968,1023.5
224,"Resto do mundo",1984-07-06,6,7,1984,15222.36
225,"Spain",1964-01-01,1,1,1964,235.8
228,"Spain",1975-01-01,1,1,1975,2128.3
231,"Austria",1972-01-01,1,1,1972,583
232,"Austria",1958-01-01,1,1,1958,345
240,"France",1966-11-26,26,11,1966,299
240,"India",1998-01-01,1,1,1998,2472
240,"Italy",1978-01-01,1,1,1978,2994.7
240,"Japan",1990-01-01,1,1,1990,16068.5
240,"Resto do mundo",1970-01-01,1,1,1970,2998.2
240,"Resto do mundo",2015-12-01,1,12,2015,32057.7
240,"United States",1961-01-28,28,1,1961,462.5
250,"India",2006-01-01,1,1,2006,2722
250,"United States",1977-01-01,1,1,1977,12671.7
259,"Resto do mundo",2016-12-31,31,12,2016,34012.7
260,"Japan",1970-01-01,1,1,1970,2246.5
260,"United States",1971-01-01,1,1,1971,5199.5
270,"Resto do mundo",1979-01-01,1,1,1979,8262.2
276,"Resto do mundo",1984-01-01,1,1,1984,14998.36
288,"Japan",1976-06-01,1,6,1976,6120.5
289,"Austria",1980-01-01,1,1,1980,2017
292,"Resto do mundo",1974-01-01,1,1,1974,6074.2
295,"Austria",1976-01-01,1,1,1976,878
300,"Resto do mundo",1977-01-01,1,1,1977,6932.2
300,"Resto do mundo",2018-01-01,1,1,2018,36252.7
300,"Resto do mundo",1974-12-31,31,12,1974,5782.2
302,"Resto do mundo",1983-08-31,31,8,1983,14006.36
303,"Japan",1968-01-01,1,1,1968,803.5
310,"France",1975-01-01,1,1,1975,609
314,"United States",1973-01-01,1,1,1973,11821.7
315,"Resto do mundo",1985-01-01,1,1,1985,18774.5
315,"Spain",1964-01-01,1,1,1964,550.8
317,"Japan",1981-02-01,1,2,1981,9383.5
324,"United States",1967-01-01,1,1,1967,3256.5
330,"Italy",1975-01-01,1,1,1975,2754.7
336,"Resto do mundo",1981-01-01,1,1,1981,11740.36
340,"Japan",1969-11-01,1,11,1969,1986.5
350,"Japan",1965-01-01,1,1,1965,500.5
350,"Resto do mundo",1982-01-01,1,1,1982,13704.36
360,"Austria",1988-01-01,1,1,1988,2485
360,"Austria",2018-12-31,31,12,2018,4470
360,"Germany",1967-01-01,1,1,1967,1123.2
360,"Resto do mundo",1975-06-01,1,6,1975,6632.2
360,"Resto do mundo",1963-12-31,31,12,1963,936.6
360,"Spain",1977-01-01,1,1,1977,2488.3
360,"Spain",1982-01-01,1,1,1982,3146.3
370,"Resto do mundo",1977-01-01,1,1,1977,7302.2
384,"Resto do mundo",1996-01-01,1,1,1996,24628.3
400,"India",1988-01-01,1,1,1988,2232
400,"Japan",2014-06-09,9,6,2014,24941.78
400,"Resto do mundo",1988-05-01,1,5,1988,20881.5
400,"United States",1965-01-01,1,1,1965,1302.5
420,"China",1991-09-01,1,9,1991,483
420,"Resto do mundo",1979-11-25,25,11,1979,10346.2
424,"United States",1968-01-01,1,1,1968,4499.5
430,"Austria",2014-01-01,1,1,2014,4110
440,"Resto do mundo",1965-10-15,15,10,1965,2540.6
440,"United States",1963-01-01,1,1,1963,902.5
440,"United States",1970-01-01,1,1,1970,4939.5
445,"France",1983-01-01,1,1,1983,3244
450,"Resto do mundo",1978-01-01,1,1,1978,7992.2
460,"Japan",1981-05-01,1,5,1981,9066.5
466,"Japan",1970-07-01,1,7,1970,2712.5
468,"Spain",1985-01-01,1,1,1985,3833.4
480,"Austria",2011-09-07,7,9,2011,3680
480,"France",1979-01-01,1,1,1979,1889
480,"Germany",1974-01-01,1,1,1974,1826.7
500,"Japan",1975-01-01,1,1,1975,5212.5
500,"Resto do mundo",1979-01-01,1,1,1979,8762.2
500,"Resto do mundo",1984-01-01,1,1,1984,15722.36
500,"Resto do mundo",2002-01-01,1,1,2002,26761.1
511.2,"United States",1978-12-01,1,12,1978,14834.9
520,"Resto do mundo",2004-12-31,31,12,2004,29190.1
525,"Austria",2009-05-01,1,5,2009,3010
560,"United States",1966-03-07,7,3,1966,1862.5
568,"Italy",1973-01-01,1,1,1973,1424.7
600,"Italy",1991-01-01,1,1,1991,5912.7
600,"Japan",1987-01-01,1,1,1987,14778.5
600,"Japan",1996-01-01,1,1,1996,19069.78
600,"United States",1974-01-01,1,1,1974,12421.7
600,"United States",1985-01-01,1,1,1985,17112.9
603,"Resto do mundo",1972-01-01,1,1,1972,3757.2
614,"Resto do mundo",1982-09-23,23,9,1982,13354.36
615,"Japan",1984-01-01,1,1,1984,12978.5
620,"Japan",1976-01-01,1,1,1976,5832.5
623,"Japan",1969-01-01,1,1,1969,1646.5
640,"Resto do mundo",1986-01-01,1,1,1986,19431.5
650,"Resto do mundo",1996-06-20,20,6,1996,25278.3
675,"Japan",1973-06-01,1,6,1973,4512.5
709,"Resto do mundo",2004-05-01,1,5,2004,28670.1
710,"United States",1973-12-19,19,12,1973,9100.7
716,"Resto do mundo",1983-01-01,1,1,1983,14722.36
720,"Resto do mundo",1991-01-01,1,1,1991,21685.3
730,"Austria",1979-01-01,1,1,1979,1608
735.16,"Resto do mundo",1981-01-01,1,1,1981,11404.36
736,"Resto do mundo",2016-12-31,31,12,2016,33753.7
748,"France",1986-01-01,1,1,1986,3992
750,"Resto do mundo",1986-02-14,14,2,1986,20181.5
778,"Resto do mundo",2016-12-31,31,12,2016,32835.7
780,"Japan",1981-02-01,1,2,1981,10163.5
788,"Resto do mundo",1995-01-01,1,1,1995,24073.3
800,"China",1997-06-01,1,6,1997,1455
800,"France",1976-01-01,1,1,1976,1409
810,"Spain",1970-01-01,1,1,1970,1595.3
819,"United States",1967-01-01,1,1,1967,4075.5
900,"India",2008-02-01,1,2,2008,5072
900,"Japan",1994-01-01,1,1,1994,16968.5
900,"Resto do mundo",2017-01-01,1,1,2017,34912.7
900,"Resto do mundo",2000-12-19,19,12,2000,26261.1
910,"France",1982-12-01,1,12,1982,2799
910,"Germany",1976-01-01,1,1,1976,2900.7
940,"Japan",2012-01-01,1,1,2012,24341.78
1000,"China",2009-02-01,1,2,2009,14487
1000,"China",2008-12-01,1,12,2008,11087
1000,"China",2011-08-14,14,8,2011,16687
1000,"China",2006-12-20,20,12,2006,8863
1000,"India",2016-12-31,31,12,2016,6072
1000,"Italy",1973-01-01,1,1,1973,2424.7
1000,"Italy",1985-01-01,1,1,1985,5312.7
1000,"Italy",1991-01-01,1,1,1991,6912.7
1000,"Japan",1982-01-01,1,1,1982,12363.5
1000,"Resto do mundo",2015-01-01,1,1,2015,31606.7
1000,"Resto do mundo",1981-05-01,1,5,1981,12740.36
1008,"Resto do mundo",1985-08-01,1,8,1985,18459.5
1040,"Resto do mundo",2013-01-01,1,1,2013,30606.7
1040,"Resto do mundo",2018-01-01,1,1,2018,35952.7
1050,"Germany",1979-01-01,1,1,1979,3950.7
1050,"Japan",1988-07-01,1,7,1988,15828.5
1060,"Germany",2004-10-20,20,10,2004,5212.7
1065,"United States",1991-01-01,1,1,1991,21380.7
1070,"United States",1966-01-01,1,1,1966,2932.5
1095,"United States",1995-01-01,1,1,1995,22520.7
1096,"Resto do mundo",1964-04-17,17,4,1964,2100.6
1119,"United States",1972-01-01,1,1,1972,6396.5
1125,"Japan",1972-01-01,1,1,1972,3837.5
1139,"Spain",1986-01-01,1,1,1986,4972.4
1160,"United States",1973-07-01,1,7,1973,10260.7
1164,"Resto do mundo",1979-01-01,1,1,1979,9926.2
1184,"Italy",1981-01-01,1,1,1981,4312.7
1200,"China",2010-10-01,1,10,2010,15687
1200,"China",2011-12-15,15,12,2011,17887
1200,"China",2009-10-16,16,10,2009,12287
1200,"China",2013-12-20,20,12,2013,22735
1200,"China",2009-11-21,21,11,2009,13487
1200,"China",2012-09-29,29,9,2012,21535
1200,"Japan",1982-01-01,1,1,1982,11363.5
1200,"Japan",1996-04-01,1,4,1996,20269.78
1200,"Japan",1986-07-01,1,7,1986,14178.5
1200,"Japan",2011-07-01,1,7,2011,23401.78
1200,"Resto do mundo",2003-11-05,5,11,2003,27961.1
1206,"Japan",1980-01-01,1,1,1980,8606.5
1212,"United States",1984-06-30,30,6,1984,16512.9
1224,"China",2006-01-01,1,1,2006,10087
1224,"China",2014-11-20,20,11,2014,23959
1247,"United States",1973-01-01,1,1,1973,11507.7
1280,"Japan",1980-05-01,1,5,1980,7400.5
1450,"India",2006-06-20,20,6,2006,4172
1500,"China",2015-01-01,1,1,2015,25459
1500,"Japan",1995-11-01,1,11,1995,18469.78
1500,"Resto do mundo",1973-01-01,1,1,1973,5442.2
1600,"Resto do mundo",1994-01-01,1,1,1994,23285.3
1652,"United States",1978-01-01,1,1,1978,14323.7
1670,"India",1981-01-01,1,1,1981,1832
1728,"Resto do mundo",1984-01-01,1,1,1984,17450.36
1800,"China",2005-11-01,1,11,2005,7863
1820,"France",1987-01-01,1,1,1987,5812
1836,"China",2000-12-25,25,12,2000,3441
1872,"United States",1973-01-01,1,1,1973,8390.7
1932,"Japan",1998-06-01,1,6,1998,22201.78
2000,"Spain",2013-10-14,14,10,2013,6972.4
2400,"China",2000-06-01,1,6,2000,5841
2448,"China",2011-06-15,15,6,2011,20335
3003,"United States",1985-12-01,1,12,1985,20115.9
730,"Austria",2019-01-01,1,1,2019,1608
1060,"Germany",2019-01-01,1,1,2019,5212.7
1184,"Italy",2019-01-01,1,1,2019,4312.7
1670,"India",2019-01-01,1,1,2019,1832
1728,"Resto do mundo",2019-01-01,1,1,2019,17450.36
1820,"France",2019-01-01,1,1,2019,5812
1932,"Japan",2019-01-01,1,1,2019,22201.78
2000,"Spain",2019-01-01,1,1,2019,6972.4
2448,"China",2019-01-01,1,1,2019,20335
3003,"United States",2019-01-01,1,1,2019,20115.9
```
````

Comment: Já sei o problema, vc tem oq chamamos de missing implicitos, n tem dados em todos os anos para todos os países

Comment: Eu imaginei isso @Bruno , você sabe como resolver ou manobrar isso?

Comment: Vc tb tem dados duplicados nos anos

Comment: Exemplo 1985 no resto do mundo tem duas linhas

Comment: @Bruno essa duplicidade acontece devido a data da coluna Commissioned ter em dois periodos do mesmo ano, porem eu não estou usando o ano no eixo x, uso da data completa da coluna Commissioned

Comment: talvez essas duas datas compliquem o meu gráfico chega em 150k mas fica feio, foi mal não tenho com responder hj

Comment: @Bruno é por volta desse número (150k) que calculei que daria. Vlw por se manifestar!

Comment: Não estou conseguindo reproduzir com os dados que você passou, mas a solução passar por trocar o argumento `position` de `geom_area` de `"dodge"` para `"stack"`

Comment: @TomásBarcellos Quando eu removo o position = position_dodge(width = 0) ele fica um gráfico totalmente errado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como apontado nos comentários, há dois problemas nos seus dados: 1) nem todas as datas possuem valores para todos os países (NAs implícitos); 2) mais de um valor para um mesmo país em uma mesma data.

Solução:

- converter seu data.frame para formato largo e depois de novo para formato longo, de modo a todas as datas estarem presentes para todos os países
- fazer isso usando uma função que agregue valores duplicados
- preencher os valores ausentes entre datas com o valor da última célula preenchida (ou com uma interpolação linear, etc)
- converter os NAs no começo das séries de cada país para 0

Estou usando o pacote *data.table* por uma questão de preferência pessoal. O mesmo pode ser feito com *tidyverse* ou com *reshape2* mais funções base do R (`approx`, `is.na`, etc).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

# Carrega os dados como data.table
novo <- fread("dados.csv")
# pode usar setDT(novo) para converter de data.frame para data.table

# Converte para formato largo, agregando valores duplicados e preenchendo os ausentes com NA
gdados <- dcast(novo,
                Commissioned ~ Country,
                value.var = "somaacumulada",
                fun = mean, # ou outra função mais relevante para seus dados
                fill = NA)
# ou reshape2::dcast ou tidyr::spread
# pode usar também a ~ Country para ter linhas mais suaves, como no seu gráfico de exemplo

# Converte de volta para formato longo
gdados <- melt(gdados,
               id.vars = "Commissioned",
               variable.name = "Country",
               value.name = "somaacumulada")
# ou reshape2::melt ou tidyr::gather

# Converte datas para formato Date
gdados[, Commissioned := as.Date(Commissioned)]

# Ordena os dados por país e data
setorder(gdados, Country, Commissioned)

# Preenche os NAs subsequentes com o último valor presente
gdados[, acum := nafill(somaacumulada, type = "locf"), by = Country]
# nafill faz parte do pacote data.table; verifique ?approx se estiver usando apenas o pacote base

# Converte os NAs no início das séries para 0
gdados[, acum := nafill(acum, fill = 0), by = Country]
# ou gdados[is.na(gdados)] <- 0 se usar o pacote base

ggplot(gdados, aes(Commissioned, acum, fill = Country)) +
  geom_area() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "10 years",
              date_labels = "%Y",
              limits = c(as.Date("1939-01-01"), max(gdados$Commissioned))) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = 'Potência Instalada [MW]', fill = NULL) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, já salvou meu dia! No código eu reparei que o limits, no " scale_x_date", começa em 1939, porem na plotagem está começando em 1935, teria como alterar isso? Perguntou pois estou tentando limitar o gráfico para o ano de 1929 e no máximo até o ano de 2019 utilizando essa propriedade e estou conseguindo o mesmo resultado que você

Comment: Por padrão o ggplot expande os limites da área de plotagem, pode eliminar isso com `scale_x_date(..., expand = c(0,0))`